# Gnome/Ubuntu only starts when in nomodeset

Tags: boot, nomodeset

computer info:

- HP Pavillion Notebook // OS: Windows 10, Home Single Language 64 bits //
  BIOS: F.23 ///  Proc: AMD A10-9600P

*First of all I'm an absolute beginner with Linux and programming in general + english is not my first language so if you would be patient enough to explain me how to get stuff done it'd be amazing. And pardon all the incorrect terminology I'm probably going to use.*

So I have been trying to install ubuntu 17.04 on my computer via a bootable usb but so far Ubuntu always freezes on the purple screen, I was finally able to enter by adding nomodeset.

Once I'm in nomodeset the graphics are of course lower in quality and I wanted to fix that issue so that I'd be able to have the normal resolution, I read a forum suggesting to go the terminal and add some lines. I had to use gksudo but it was not installed, when I tried to install it it said apt-get could not fnd ubuntu servers. Then, I tried to connect to the internet but the connection was too slow and kept disconnecting (which does not happens in windows)

I also tried to start fedora but it showed a lot of fails and I could not get it to run.

Judging by fedora error messages there may be an issue with AMD, however ubuntu does not display any related error.

(Before the purple screen appears it always shows "No Caching mode page found")

EDIT:
I tried with Ubuntu Gnome and the same thing happened, unless I state nomodeset the screen freezes at the logo wallpaper, other than that it runs smoothly and I faced none of the other issues I experienced on ubuntu 17.04

**Is there any way to run gnome without nomodeset / install in nomodeset then return to high quality graphics?**

Comment: Open your terminal and type `sudo lshw -c display` then edit your question again and include the output for us please.